# SpringMVC : Throws 415 Unsupported Media Type while attempting POST request call for redirection

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, java-8, tomcat8, spring-4

Browser response like below:

**The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.**

**Instead of** redirecting to the home page ( home.jsp  )

welcome.jsp file:

```
<form method ="POST" action = "<c:url value='/login'/>" >

       <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
       <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
       <input type="submit" id="loginNew" value="LoginNew"> 
  </form>
```

Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/login" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ModelAndView authenticate ( @RequestBody User userObj ) throws Exception {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView ();
        try {
            user = userService.authenticateUser ( userObj );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        modelAndView.setViewName("/home");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding **@ModelAttribute** instead of @RequestBody in the method param solved the issue  and then redirected to the home.jsp page as expected.

```
@RequestMapping( value="/login" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
        public ModelAndView authenticate ( @ModelAttribute User userObj ) throws Exception {
           ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView ();
            try {
                user = userService.authenticateUser ( userObj );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
            modelAndView.setViewName("/home");
            return modelAndView;
        }
```